# Is there slack api command to play a bell or tune on all clients machines in a channel?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I would like to play a Bell chime to all clients in a slack channel when somebody makes a sale.  Is that possible in slack-api and if so where can I begin looking.

All my searches appear to come up with embedded audio players.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such method currently. You can check all available methods here: https://api.slack.com/methods

You could however [send a message](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage) in which you mention [@everyone](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-formatting#variables). This would at least notify everyone who is in the same channel.

If you are within the same office and the sound aspect is important to you, you could implement a custom solution with external speakers in your office. ^^